# Regex removing empty spaces when using replace

Tags: c#, regex

My situation is not about removing empty spaces, but keeping them. I have this string `>[database values]` which I would like to find. I created this `RegEx` to find it then go in and remove the `>, [, ]`. The code below takes a string that is from a document. The first pattern looks for anything that is surrounded by `>[some stuff]` it then goes in and "removes" `>, [, ]`

```
  string decoded = "document in string format";
  string pattern = @">\[[A-z, /, \s]*\]";
  string pattern2 = @"[>, \[, \]]"; 
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
  Regex rgx2 = new Regex(pattern2);         
  foreach (Match match in rgx.Matches(decoded))
  {                     
    string replacedValue= rgx2.Replace(match.Value, "");
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(replacedValue);
```

What I am getting in first my `Console.WriteLine` is correct. So I would be getting things like `>[123 sesame St]`. But my second output shows that my replace removes not just the characters but the spaces so I would get something like this `123sesameSt`. I don't see any space being replaced in my `Regex`. Am I forgetting something, perhaps it is implicitly in a replace?

Comment: to complete ScoJo answer: `[A-z]` is different from `[A-Za-z]` since the hyphen define a range. Take a look at the ascii table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[A-z, /, \s]` and `[>, \[, \]]` in your patterns are also looking for commas and spaces.  Just list the characters without delimiting them, like this: `[A-Za-z/\s]`

```
string pattern = @">\[[A-Za-z/\s]*\]";
string pattern2 = @"[>,\[\]]";
```

Edit to include Casimir's tip.

Answer (score 1):

By defining `[>, \[, \]]` in `pattern2` you define a [character group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) consisting of single characters like `>`, `,`, , `[` and every other character you listed in the square brackets. But I guess you don't want to match space  and `,`. So if you don't want to match them leave them out like

```
string pattern2 = @"[>\[\]]";
```

Alternatively, you could use

```
string pattern2 = @"(>\[|\])";
```

Thereby, you either match `>[` or `]` which better expresses your intention.

Answer (score 1):

After rereading your question (if I understand well) I realize that your two steps approach is useless. You only need one replacement using a capture group:

```
string pattern = @">\[([^]]*)]";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

string result = rgx.Replace(yourtext, "$1");
```

pattern details:

```
>\[         # literals: >[
(           # open the capture group 1
    [^]]*   # all that is not a ]
)           # close the capture group 1
]           # literal ]
```

the replacement string refers to the capture group 1 with `$1`

Comment: It a bit more complicated, this is just a generalize version that contains the functionality I am looking for.